# getting PSQL error with Rails 5 although I'm not using the PG gem in my Gemfile, and database.yml doesn't include any Postgresql reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I deleted postgres from my machine by

```
brew rm postgresql --force
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I created a new rails app. This is my standard gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Then

```
bundle install
rails s
```

Although I haven't specified any pg gem in my gemfile I am getting the error when trying to get to localhost

```
> Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. 
> Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile 
> (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
> Extracted source (around line #176):

require path_to_adapter
rescue Gem::LoadError => eraise Gem::LoadError, 
"Specified '#{spec[:adapter]}' for database adapter, 
but the gem is not loaded. 
Add `gem '#{e.name}'` to your Gemfile   
(and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)."
rescue LoadError => eraise LoadError,  
"Could not load '#{path_to_adapter}'. 
Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. 
If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'     
add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.", e.backtrace
end
```

This is my database.yml file which doesn'r include any postgres either.

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

What's the problem here? Before I was using sqlite in dev and test, and pg in production. There still seem to be some references in the system which I obviously couldn't get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

Write in your console:

## echo $DATABASE_URL

IF RESULT IS:

## postgresql://user:password@localhost/database

Look for in your .bash_profile or .profile

export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:password@localhost/database"

Comment this line and to be happy.

Read here

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Section 3.5

"When duplicate connection information is provided the environment variable (DATABASE_URL) will take precedence"

Answer (score 0):

You still have postgres listed as your adaptor in your database.yml file.  Once you change your database.yml to reflect the fact that you are not using postgres you will need to run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: my database.yml doesn't include any postgres reference. Re-edited my question and included the yml content

Comment: I ran `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` and got the error _rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)._